# Anonymizing survey data, plus an ethics question

Tags: categorical-data, dataset, ethics

This is a fairly simple question about raw data in Excel. I have a survey asking respondents to rate 17 questions on a rating scale from 1 to 5. The goal is for individuals who answer the survey to be anonymous. There are also demographic questions. For the sake of anonymity, we don't want someone to be able to match a single response to all of its demographic answers. Dissecting by all the demographic indicators could probably get you an individual person, and we don't want to report groups smaller than 10 people (arbitrary limit, management picked it). If a survey response is paired with a single demographic indicator, it usually creates groups of responses larger than 10. There are about 40,000 responses to this survey.

So my first question is: Say I have 3 demographic questions. I copy all results of the 17 rating questions on to 3 tabs, and on each tab I include one of the 3 demographic indicators next to the survey data. Then I randomize the order of responses on all 3 tabs. I assume it's possible to de-anonymize this, so **What would be a better way to anonymize the data?**

My concern is that there are about a trillion different possible permutations of survey answers, so someone could use the order of survey responses as a unique identifier. BUT: there are going to be repetitions, so they could never de-anonymize it completely. About 17% of the responses have at least 1 clone.

Second question: **If we guarantee respondents anonymity, would we be maintaining that promise if we reported the data as proposed?** I recognize that there is a risk of the data being de-anonymized, but the data will be going mostly to people who are not very data savvy, and who honestly probably don't care enough to try to de-anonymize it. Thoughts?

Comment: How would anyone know the survey answers so that she could use them to de-anonymize the data? What exactly is your survey about?

Comment: Even if the question is 9 years old, I've been trying to answer it, but I realize that without knowing how the third party intends to use the data, it's impossible to suggest a solution satisfying to everyone involved (unless by writing a book on all anonymization and de-identification methods). So I suggest to close the question as lacking enough details. On a side note, sharing raw data with a non-tech savvy third party may be a liability, as they are certainly more vulnerable to data breach and cyberattacks, no matter the good intentions they may have.

Comment: Just in case someone else stumble upon this question and is looking for solutions to a similar problem, a straightforward solution is to *not* share the raw data with the third party, and instead generate the output the third party is interested in (be it crosstables, boxplots, etc.). Still, even with this solution, you should check if the outputs allow re-identification. It may require to throw some noise in your data, merge some small-occurrence categories with other categories, etc. Asking a new question about your specific situation is probably a good idea.